# How do I move a user to a specific channel on discord using the discord.py API

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Okay, so I know the command to do this but my issue is I do not know what arguments to pass to the parameters. I want my code to take a user's message content and then move the user to a voice channel named "afk". Here is a snippet of my code:

All I want to do is move a user that types the words !move in any case to be moved to another voice channel. 
I am sorry if my code is bad but I just need this down.

I know you might need to see my definitions but all it is:

```
def on_message(message):
    if '!MOVE' in message.content.upper():
        author = message.author
        voice_channel = id('afk')
        await client.move_member(author, voice_channel)
```

Comment: What is `id('afk')`?

Comment: Just a place holder for what channel id I want to be included. I want to move a member to the channel called afk. That is the name of one of my channels.

Comment: It actually means nothing really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`client.move_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.move_member) takes two arguments: a `Member` and a `Channel`.  We can use [`discord.utils.find`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.find) to get the channel from the servers list of channels.

```
channel = discord.utils.find(lambda x: x.name == 'afk', message.server.channels)
await client.move_member(message.author, channel)
```

Some further notes:

- The above is actually unnecessary for the afk channel, as servers have a [`Server.afk_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Server.afk_channel) attribute.
- You should also be using the `discord.ext.commands` extension to implement your commands, to keep your `on_message` from getting cluttered.

Comment: That removed the syntax error, but it does not move the author of the message to the channel.

Comment: Are you getting any output in the terminal running the bot?

Comment: nvm nvm I figured it out Thank you. You forgot to add the s to utils when you were calling the discord utility. Thank you man.