# Discord move user in other channel

Tags: c#, discord

I've tried to move a user to another channel. For this reason I've used user.ModifyAsync. But the server responded with error 400: BadRequest reply.

My code is:

```
private async void move_user(SocketGuildUser user, ulong new_channel)
    {
        await user.ModifyAsync(x=> { x.ChannelId = new_channel; });
    }
```

I tried it with the latest discord.net nuget package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move a user to a specific channel on discord using the discord.py API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873638/how-do-i-move-a-user-to-a-specific-channel-on-discord-using-the-discord-py-api)

Comment: The code appears to be correct. You may be getting that error because the user is not currently in a voice channel. You can't add a user to a voice channel if they are not in one, you can only move them to another voice channel once they are already connected.

Comment: @champion-runner nope, that's Python, this is C#